# display a history of result

Tags: php, html, post, calculator

I want to display results of the calculation at the end of the program as a list. After each post, the result is added to the list of previous results.
Simply, I want to display a history of the result of the calculations done.

```
<form method="post" >

    <p>A:<input value="<?php echo $_POST['num1']?>" min="0" max="1000" type="number" name="num1"></p>
    <p>B:<input value="<?php echo $_POST['num2']?>" min="0" max="1000" type="number" name="num2"></p>
    <p>
        <select name="op">
            <option value="jaam">+</option>
            <option value="zarb">*</option>
            <option value="taghtsim">/</option>
            <option value="tafrigh">-</option>
        </select>
    </p>
<input type="submit" name="">
<hr>
</form>




<?php
    if (isset($_POST['num1']) && isset($_POST['num2']) && isset($_POST['op']))
    {
        switch ($_POST['op'])
        {
            case 'jaam':
                $r = $_POST['num1'] + $_POST['num2'];
                break;
            case 'zarb':
                $r = $_POST['num1'] * $_POST['num2'];
                break;
            case 'taghtsim':
                $r = $_POST['num1'] / $_POST['num2'];
                break;
            case 'tafrigh':
                $r = $_POST['num1'] - $_POST['num2'];
                break;
            default:
                $r = "Error!";
                break;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Put the history in a session variable, and add to it each time the form is submitted.

Comment: Why can't you use javascript, it won't have to load everytime you do a calculation and the logic won't include alot like using cookies